# Where to store assets for multiple web apps

Tags: mysql, web, assets, web-development-server

I am working on a project that is consisted of multiple web applications communicating through some messaging system. Those applications need to be looking at some assets like images and so. Is storing images in MySQL database as blobs a good idea? or should I be using another tool.

Notes:

- I cannot use a hosting server because it's not guaranteed to have internet connection where the applications are deployed.
- Applications are to be deployed on different machines.

Comment: This is not a Stack Overflow question: It's too opinion based and highly situational. Would putting everything on a CD-ROM and passing it around be an option? Who knows. You'll need to **try things** and see what works.

Comment: I agree with tadman. This absolutely depends on the particular set up you have, type and usage of data etc. Generally speaking, data that are dynamically generated from elsewhere (users, other systems etc) go to a database. Static data, like icons, default images for anonymous users, html, css etc. are served by a web server. The exception proves the rule, though. There may be very good reasons for doing it in a complete other fashion.

Comment: I actually needed to gain some insight and know the usual thing that people do in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

While you can store images in a database, you must carefully consider the size of each image and the number of images to be stored.  Both of these will affect the optimal server memory size needed for both performance reasons and to backup your application.

You also indicated that an Internet connection is not guaranteed where the applications are to be deployed.  This would make storage of images on a content delivery network (CDN) impractical.

As you plan how "multiple web applications communicate through some messaging system", that might suggest some methods of sharing images between hosts.